# Revert model to t-pose

Tags: pose-mode

I'm aware of the "Rest Position" button, but I'm looking to somehow get the model to a T-pose in "Pose Position" (because you can't pose the model if it's in "Rest Position" mode), so I can pose it from there. I downloaded a rigged model and it wasn't in T-pose, but I want to revert it to a T-pose to make it easier to pose the model.

I'm hoping there's a button because I can't find some of the bones

Wow that's a lot of pose hope it's not too unclear

Comment: How about clearing all the transformations, by selecting all the pose bones and pressing Alt G (to clear location), Alt R (to clear rotation) and Alt S (to clear scale).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To return to the original pose, simply reset all the transformations.

Make sure your are in Pose Mode, by selecting the Armature and choosing Pose Mode in the 3D View (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Then select all bones (<kbd>A</kbd>) and press

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to reset location
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset rotation
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to reset scale